# Prove that adding an edge e1 and removing e2 to a tree T result in a tree

Tags: graph-theory

Let T be a tree on n vertices.

Suppose you add one more edge, call it e, to T (the number of vertices is kept the same). Call the
resulting graph T'. Let C denote the cycle in T′. You now remove one edge, call it f, from C. Prove that the resulting
graph, $T'' = T' \{f\}$, is a tree. Note that T′′ is not necessarily equal to T since any edge can be
deleted from C (i.e., f need not equal e).

I started with showing that for all vertices (u,v) in T’’, there is a path that connects u to v, but I am not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

$T''$ is connected: Given vertices $u,v$, consider the path from $u$ to $v$ in $T$. If this path does not use $f$, we are done. If it does use $f$, replace $f$ with its complement in $C$.

A connected graph on $n$ vertices is a tree iff it has $n-1$ edges.

Answer (score 0):

Since $T$ is a tree, a cycle $C$ occurs when a new edge $e$ is added. So $T^\prime$ is a connected graph with a cycle. When an edge $f$ from cycle $C$ is deleted, the resulting graph becomes a cycle-free, connected graph. Thus, $T^{\prime\prime}$ is a tree.